# Delete Product Magento 2

Tags: magento2, error, products, delete

I want to delete products by sctip.

They way I am doing it for test :

```
if(!empty($products))
        {
            foreach($products as $_product)
            {
            $sku = $_product->getSku();

            $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
            $productRepository = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository');
            $registry = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
            $registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
            $productRepository->deleteById($sku);
        }
    }
```

I am getting Error:

```
 [Magento\Framework\Exception\StateException]
  Unable to remove product 1000180701
```

EDIT:

Full Code, i am using a Product Collection:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection $productCollection */
        $productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
        $productCollection->addFieldToSelect('*');
        $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('sku',array('nin'=> $aProductIds));
        /** Apply filters here */
        $products = $productCollection->load();

        if(!empty($products))
        {
            foreach($products as $_product)
            {
                $sku = $_product->getSku();


                $registry = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Registry');
                $registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
                $_product->delete();
            }
        }
```

Throwing:

```
[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Delete operation is forbidden for current area
```

Answer (score 3):

If you change this:

> $registry = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Registry');

To:

> $registry = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Registry');

It should work I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If `$products` is a collection of products you don't need to do all that.

You can simply do:

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $product->delete();
}
```

Comment: Outputs: 

[Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException]
  Delete operation is forbidden for current area  - I also added the register Part but didnt change anything. BTW it's a productCollection.

Comment: @Ecoplan what is the the class of `$products` variable ?

Comment: $products is a loaded collection

Comment: @Ecoplan you still getting the `Delete operation is forbidden for current area ` error even after adding the register part ?

Comment: watch my edited post

Comment: @Ecoplan interesting, I'm not sure what the problem is here

Comment: yeah it's kinda crazy do u know any other way to delte Product by id or sku ?

Comment: @Ecoplan no it seems to be the right way

Answer (score 1):

I have to fetch the same issue so create a test file root directory and **add below code...**

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\AppInterface;
try {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo 'Autoload error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit(1);
}
try{
    $bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
    $appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $appState->setAreaCode('frontend');

    $productID = 11;
    $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', true);
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productID);
    $product->delete();
    echo ' successfully remove..';
}
catch(\Exception $e){
    print_r($e->getMessage());
}
```

may be your issue resolve...

Answer (score 0):

You can also delete product via the Magento 2 Import process.

Just create a CSV file with the SKU list and then select Delete behavior from the product import in Magento 2 BO.

Moreover, I think you cannot delete products from the FO. You can only delete, edit product from Admin store.

You need to have

```
$this->registry->registry('isSecureArea')  == true
```

If you check the logic code of the regitry, you cannot overwride a regitry key

```
public function register($key, $value, $graceful = false)
{
    if (isset($this->_registry[$key])) {
        if ($graceful) {
            return;
        }
        throw new \RuntimeException('Registry key "' . $key . '" already exists');
    }
    $this->_registry[$key] = $value;
}
```

Try this :

```
$this->registry->unregister('isSecureArea')
$this->registry->register('isSecureArea', true)
```

Complete method based on Magento 2 test code :

```
/**
 * Enable secure/admin area
 *
 * @param bool $flag
 * @return void
 */
protected static function _enableSecureArea($flag = true)
{
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->unregister('isSecureArea');
    if ($flag) {
        $objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Registry')->register('isSecureArea', $flag);
    }
}
```

And try to use Dependancy injection whereas objectmanager.

Answer (score 0):

Your registry key : `$objectManager->create('\Magento\Framework\Registry')`

This should be **Magento\Framework\Registry** instead of `\Magento\Framework\Registry`.

The full snippet :

```php
$registry = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Registry');
$registry->register('isSecureArea', true);
$_product->delete();
```